# How can I recursively query mongoDB using findOne({}) until all the task from an external API has completed working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, callback

I have a node.js, express and mongoose setup, I am exporting the modules with express:

```
module.exports.taskData = (jobId, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
           MyModel.findOne({jobId: jobId}, function(err, newCallback) {
                   if (err) callback(err)
                      callback(null, newCallback)
                       taskStage = newCallback.taskDetails.map(obj => ['stage'])
                        for (let i = 0; i < taskStage.length; i++{
                                if (taskStage === 'done') {
                                    doTheNextTask()
                                } else {
                                   //wait for task to be done.
                                   //trying to call findOne again not working. 
                               }
                            }
                        })
                }, 3000);
}
```

After I call an API(external) from another module, the jobId is generated then I pass it to taskData module so that i can gather the data and save it in MongoDb after the external  API requested task is complete. The task API will have three stages that will be saved to MongoDB. once task is started, it saves document then once the task is in progress, it will save into another document and done, same thing. so the data is streaming. I am able to save all the received payload. but my issue is the findOne query run once and only returns the document with stage "started"

However, my objective is to receive only the details of documents at stage "done" after the task has been completed. How can i achieve this using callback or more preferable async/await and Promises, or just regular ole recursion.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear, is the code you are trying to write supposed to (a) *coordinate* a "started/in-progress/done" process or (b) *monitor* a "started/in-progress/done" process that is coordinated elsewhere?

Comment: Not monitor the process of the external api but rather monitor for change in stages after the process has been done and saved in my mongoDB (at real time)  i.e., check if  "started/inprogress/done" and if it's at done run a query. but since it is at real time findOne only run once and return started before the process goes from start -> save, inprogress -> save,  done -> save

Comment: it's a synchronous process. 1 task begins, then for each stage it saves to my database. I am trying to recursively/asynchronously  check only my database for each stage(changes) and only get the task details that are marked as done.( I might be going the wrong way about)

Comment: From what I understand, your problem is similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31873295/3478010). The selected answer may offer a way ahead.